# Ternary Operator in Multiple conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I have one if condition in c#

```
    if (item.ReporSubCategoryId == 1 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 2 || 
        item.ReporSubCategoryId == 3 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 4)
    {
<a  href="@Url.Action("GetPdf", "Report", new { report = item.ReporSubCategoryId })" >@item.ReportTitle</a>
    }
```

I want to this if condition change to be used ternary operator ?

for using show and  hide this  a tag
(`style='display:Myconditions?block:None'`)

```
<a  href="@Url.Action("GetPdf", "Report", new { report = item.ReporSubCategoryId })" >@item.ReportTitle</a>
```

But i try this code

```
<a style='display:" @item.ReporSubCategoryId == 1 || @item.ReporSubCategoryId == 2 || @item.ReporSubCategoryId == 3 || @item.ReporSubCategoryId == 4 ?block:None"'href="@Url.Action("GetPdf", "Report", new { report = item.ReporSubCategoryId })" >@item.ReportTitle</a>
```

But it's not working. Can you give the  correct solution for my wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one..

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ReportTitle, "GetPdf", "Report", new { report = item.ReporSubCategoryId }, 
 new { @style = "display:" 
  (item.ReporSubCategoryId == 1 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 2 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 3 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 4)
   ? "block" : "none" }
})
```

it adds "block"/"none" as per your condition

```
(item.ReporSubCategoryId == 1 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 2 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 3 || item.ReporSubCategoryId == 4)
```

Comment: you mean to say that the link has got hidden, but it still consumes the space in the page. Am I right?

Comment: it must be a confusion.see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtNdK/) **visibility: hidden** hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.
**display: none** removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code. - as per [this link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm)